# Mailchimp static segments is updating but not for campaign

Tags: mailchimp

I'm doing static segments update via the Mailchimp API, when I go on mailchimp website I see the changes appearing, but when I try to create a campaign from it, it show outdated data.

In the example here I did:

- Create New Static segment created via API,
- Add 611 Emails via API,
- Remove the 611 Emails via API
- Go on website, see empty segment as expected
- Create a campaign from this empty segment
- Findout 611 unexpected emails in the segment.

PrintScreen of mailchimp :
[image: PrintScreen of mailchimp]

How can I have it synced?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution for this problem? Also, I have noticed that changes in the segments via API take around 10 minutes to be reflected